# Why Is My Google +1 Button Counts the Same Over Multiple Pages

Tags: html, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm not sure why, but the +1 buttons on my site are all showing the same number of +1's. They render fine and the tag is working. Here's the code I've put on different pages:

```
<g:plusone size="medium" href="http://example.com/" callback="GooglePlusOne"></g:plusone>

<g:plusone size="medium" href="http://example.com/episode2" callback="GooglePlusOne"></g:plusone>

<g:plusone size="medium" href="http://example.com/episode3" callback="GooglePlusOne"></g:plusone>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This looks correct according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#target-url).  Can you post the URL to the site in question?

Comment: Hey StingeyB, did you find solution? Got same error, really weird!

Comment: I never did. People had really good suggestions, but i never figured it out. A couple times it worked, but it would revert back to the old numbers where they were all the same.

Answer (score 2):

The button has a href attribute that I believe specifies the URL that you are "+1"ing, you could try removing it so it defaults to the canonical.

If that is not specified it should default to the pages Canonical link,you should then check that they aren't the same for the pages you are looking at.

Also check that the URL you are trying to +1 is publicly accessible (daft to ask but worth mentioning).

Comment: Good call on the "publicly accessible" idea.